# Multiprocessing in python on a 4GB JSON file

Tags: python, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I've got a big JSON file (4GB) and I ought to load the file and pull out the necessary data. The file contains 180k video IDs, where each videoID has a subgroup of frameIDs and each frame 4x coordinates. (around 60frames per video --> 60x180*10^3 = 1.08*10^7 annotations/lines)

Something like this (simplified):

```
   video_id_1 -> video_id_1_frame_id_1
                        --> x1,y1,x2,y2
                  video_id_1_frame_id_2
                        --> x1,y1,x2,y2
                  video_id_1_frame_id_3
                        --> x1,y1,x2,y2
                  video_id_1_frame_id_4
                        --> x1,y1,x2,y2
    video_id_2 -> video_id_2_frame_id_1
                        --> x1,y1,x2,y2
                  video_id_2_frame_id_2
                        --> x1,y1,x2,y2
                  video_id_2_frame_id_3
                        --> x1,y1,x2,y2
                  video_id_2_frame_id_4
                        --> x1,y1,x2,y2
                  video_id_2_frame_id_5
                        --> x1,y1,x2,y2
```

Real case example (Where this is an example for video_id 2 and frame 01, could be told from the 'name' label)

```
   [
{'gt_placeholders': ['pillow'],
 'labels': [{'box2d': {'x1': 97.64950730138266,
                      'x2': 427,
                      'y1': 11.889318166856967,
                      'y2': 239.92858832368972},
                      'category': 'pillow',
                      'standard_category': '0000'}},
            {'box2d': {'x1': 210.1160330781122,
                      'x2': 345.4329005999551,
                      'y1': 78.65516045335991,
                      'y2': 209.68758889799403},
                      'category': 'hand',
                      'standard_category': 'hand'}}],
 'name': '2/0001.jpg',
 'nr_instances': 2}, 
 {...},
 ...
 {...},
 ]
```

Compiling the code single-threaded it would take a day or two, hoping that the process doesn't get killed at some point. Since I've got access to very powerful machines I was hoping to use Multiprocessing in python in order to compile such a big file.

I was looking into several youtube tutorials on concurrent.futures library and how to use it, however, whenever I run a small snippet of the code(several IDs), the code compiles successfully, however, when I run the code on the 4GB JSON files, it gets killed. I assume that is due to memory overuse. The idea would be to assign a single video_id to a thread/process which would return the coordinates and store in an array of form:

```
[video_id_frame_id,      x1,       x2,       y1,      y2]
```

This is the code I wrote, it works on a simplified version, but when running on the big file it crashes.

```
if args.multiproc:
print("Starting multi processing")
# Processing MULTLIPROCESSING
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = [executor.submit(process_video, parsed_json[video]) for i,video in enumerate(parsed_json)]

    for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
        warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
        if (temp := f.result()) is not 0:
            print(temp.shape)
            if 'array' in locals():
                array = np.append(array,temp, axis=0)
            else:
                array = temp
```

My goal is to be able to process this file using Multiprocessing, ideally using GPU however I have no knowledge of doing so. I am kindly asking for some recommendations on how to approach this case, what should I be looking for, or maybe what libraries would you advise me to use. I am not looking for a solution as I want to be able to write it myself.

EDIT: I've made a change, and now I am passing over only parsed_json[video_id] and not the whole parsed_json. The compiler doesn't get killed anymore, however it stops after compiling 45 videos.

Comment: Does "some_function_wrapper" really need the whole "parsed_json"? "video" isn't enough?

Comment: Hi @MichaelButscher, it returns the whole 'parsed_json' so the function could iterate certain id. 
In the function :
    for j, frame in enumerate(parsed_json[video_id])

Now pointing this out, I assume passing over parsed_json[video_id] as an array would be better.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, I've made the change, and the code does compile now (thanks for that), however, it stopped on the 50th video.

Comment: @jokkk2312 the general principle you should adhere to is that the data you give to each process should be kept minimal. In your case, you are trying to parallelize work on a 4gb file. Therefore, if the file is already in memory and you aren't using shared state, then the ideal scenario would be that each process gets a unique subset of the json (if two or more processes get a subset which is not entirely unique then that is not ideal). Then the total memory used would be 4gb for the json in main process + 4gb for the json that is split among the processes = 8 gb.

Comment: However, you can even cut that in half by lazily iterating over the huge json from the main process. For example, create an iterator that opens a handle to the file. Then, instead of reading the whole file in memory , go line by line till you get enough data to start a process (in your case this seems to be when a `parsed_json[video]` has been read), this is what you should return in the `__next__` method of the iterator. Then instead of using `concurrent.futures`, use `multiprocessing.Pool` to create 10 processes and submit the iterator using `pool.imap`.

Comment: Additionally, lower the number of processes running concurrently if you are still using too much memory